# How to insert new users directories

Tags: samba, chown, kerberos, sssd

I am trying to set up the directories on Ubuntu Server, Linux 4.15.0-162-generic #170-Ubuntu SMP using command

```
chown user:group
```

however, I have gotten an error like

```
chown: invalid spec: ‘2163147:’
```

This picture shows some users with space (these are not working) and other no space (they are working fine).

[image]

I have set up this server using samba, sssd, krb5 and I have installed Apache2 and Nginx.

Anyone has some solution for this issue?

This is the output of `testparm -s`:

```
    /var/www/Students$ testparm -s
    Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
    rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
    WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
    Processing section "[printers]"
    Processing section "[print$]"
    Processing section "[www$]"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "security mask"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "security mask"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "force security mode"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "force security mode"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "directory security mask"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "directory security mask"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "force directory security mode"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "force directory security mode"
    Processing section "[StudentsCS$]"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "security mask"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "security mask"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "force security mode"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "force security mode"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "directory security mask"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "directory security mask"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "force directory security mode"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "force directory security mode"
    Processing section "[Dvwa$]"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "security mask"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "security mask"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "force security mode"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "force security mode"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "directory security mask"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "directory security mask"
    Unknown parameter encountered: "force directory security mode"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "force directory security mode"
    Loaded services file OK.
    Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

    # Global parameters
    [global]
            client signing = if_required
            dns proxy = No
            kerberos method = secrets and keytab
            log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
            map to guest = Bad User
            max log size = 1000
            obey pam restrictions = Yes
            pam password change = Yes
            panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
            passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
            passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
            security = USER
            server role = standalone server
            server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
            syslog = 0
            unix password sync = Yes
            usershare allow guests = Yes
            idmap config * : backend = tdb


    [printers]
            browseable = No
            comment = All Printers
            create mask = 0700
            path = /var/spool/samba
            printable = Yes


    [print$]
            comment = Printer Drivers
            path = /var/lib/samba/printers


    [www$]
            create mask = 0770
            directory mask = 02770
            force create mode = 0770
            force directory mode = 02770
            guest ok = Yes
            path = /var/www
            read only = No
            valid users = amcdonald


    [StudentsCS$]
            create mask = 0770
            directory mask = 02770
            force create mode = 0770
            force directory mode = 02770
            guest ok = Yes
            inherit acls = Yes
            inherit owner = windows and unix
            inherit permissions = Yes
            path = /var/www/Students/
            read only = No


    [Dvwa$]
            create mask = 0770
            directory mask = 02770
            force create mode = 0770
            force directory mode = 02770
            guest ok = Yes
            inherit acls = Yes
            inherit owner = windows and unix
            inherit permissions = Yes
            path = /var/www/html/
            read only = No
```

Comment: Strange one, try `chown user.group` rather than with a `:`, both should work. It may help if you tell us what the file system type is.

Comment: Here is the output:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     597M  2.9M  594M   1% /run
/dev/sda2      ext4       79G   36G   39G  48% /
Thank you for your help.

Comment: chown: invalid user: ‘6159240.’

Comment: Can you post the full command you entered, including the filename, and make sure the filename is in the screenshot?

Comment: root@uxdev:/var/www/Students# sudo usermod -a -G students 2169041
usermod: user '2169041' does not exist

Comment: sudo chown -R 6159240. /var/www/Students/6159240/
chown: invalid user: ‘6159240.’

Comment: From the man page of useradd... `Usernames must start with a lower case letter or an underscore`. I think there is confusion between whether you are giving a username or a user id.

Comment: can you post the output of 'testparm -s' so we can see how you think you are running Samba.

Comment: [StudentsCS$]
        create mask = 0770
        directory mask = 02770
        force create mode = 0770
        force directory mode = 02770
        guest ok = Yes
        inherit acls = Yes
        inherit owner = windows and unix
        inherit permissions = Yes
        path = /var/www/Students/
        read only = No

Comment: This server was joined into the domain. Do I need to synchronize the users from the AD server?

Comment: That isn't the output of 'testparm -s', please supply the output of that command

Comment: Please don't provide additional information anywhere other than in your question itself. Make it easy for people to read and understand your question - if you spread details throughout the comments it's probable some of them will be missed

Comment: You say it is joined to a domain, but your smb.conf is for a standalone server and that can never be a domain member. I would first remove all the lines marked 'Ignoring unknown parameter' and then go and read these Samba wikipages: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member and https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Idmap_config_rid

Comment: @RowlandPenny the OP added the requested output.

Comment: I am sorry @terdon for the update on the solution. This is the first time that I am using this space. Thanks for your changes.

Comment: @RodrigoNM no need to apologize! We know our rules are complex and confusing. We feel they do make for a cleaner site, but I completely understand that they feel weird for new users. Don't worry about it at all :).

Comment: Thank you @RowlandPenny for your references. I will check it and get back to you if I have any questions. Thanks for these links.

Comment: How happened that the server has been missed as a "member server"?

Comment: Because your smb.conf wasn't for a Unix domain member.